# MS Access VBA Addnew returns existing record?

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I have a database app written in Microsoft Access 2010.  Among other things it has two related tables: "Orders", which has entries for generic information about an order, and "FrameOrder" which has information about a specific type of order.  They're linked by "OrderID", which is the primary key of the "Orders" table.

The database is split into front and back ends, so these are linked tables.

Here's the code that's used to conjure up a brand new Order with a FrameOrder linking back to it:

```
Private Sub FramingQuoteButton_Click()
    ' Create a new Order of type Framing, then create a Framing Order linking back to it
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim frs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ThisOrderID As Long
    Dim ThisFrameOrderID As Long

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Orders")
    rs.AddNew
    rs!OrderType = "FRAME"
    rs!CustomerID = DefaultCustomerID()
    rs.Update
    rs.Bookmark = rs.LastModified
    ThisOrderID = rs!OrderID
    rs.Close

    Set frs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("FrameOrder")
    frs.AddNew
    frs!OrderID = ThisOrderID
    frs.Update <<<< This is where the problem shows up
    frs.Bookmark = frs.LastModified
    ThisFrameOrderID = frs!FrameOrderID
    frs.Close

    DoCmd.OpenForm "FrameOrder", , , "OrderID = " & ThisOrderID, , , "NEW"

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set frs = Nothing
End Sub
```

So first I create a brand new "Orders" entry.  Then I create a "FrameOrder" entry and set  the "OrderID" to the primary key of the "Order" I just made.

Here's the problem: sometimes when I do this, the Update line shown above throws a key error.  When I look at it in the debugger, it seems as though the frs.AddNew call generated a record whose key is that of an existing record, somewhere in the middle of the table!  If I do a "Compact And Repair Database" on the backend, the problem goes away.

Since this app is still under development, I'll often copy the front and back end files to a development system, do some work, then copy them back to the production system.  This problem shows up most frequently after I've done such a copy (yes, I make sure that the database is closed before I copy).

Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you going to all this trouble when Access will handle it for you with a form and subform set-up?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest refreshing the linked tables, sometimes if the data structure changes, the changes aren't propagated to the front end and problems like this can occur. I hope this works.